# Align every columns in the same level

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4NDW.png)
How can I move the max columns to be in the same level as the previous stats?
The collab seems to add line to separate my columns on its own.
function stack() and unstack() are not what I was looking for.